# Write a regex to include variable string surrounded by literals

Tags: regex, nginx

I am writing a nginx conf file and I would like to match a path that specifies a portion that should be treated as a variable. Suppose the root for the requests is `/foo` and within foo there are randomly named folders such as `/foo/abd` `/foo/lkd` however every randomly named folder contains a static named folder `/images`. I would like my regex to designate that second part of the URL as a variable. Something like `/foo/{{variable}}/images`

Comment: If you could please elaborate your problem. Post any code if you have.

Comment: Well I came up with `\/foo\/\w+\/images\/w+` but this does not work. There is no code. What I want is just to match a URI with a variable word between a set of `"/"`, and make it work with nginx.

Comment: Okay so you want to catch the `variable` from the URL ? If url is `/foo/xyz/images`, you want to extract only `xyz` ?

Comment: Well I want the route to match... not sure if you are familiar with nginx but there are `location` directives where you specify a regular expression and if that matches the URI, it will execute whatever is within its block. In essence I would like to ignore the `xyz`, so no matter what is between `/foo/` and `/images` it should match that route. `/foo/kfjsl/images`, `/foo/khkjhk/images` and so on.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [this](https://regex101.com/r/uW1aG8/3). Let me know if that works.

Comment: I have assumed that your variable will only contain characters from `a-z`. You can make it to match other characters by adding them in `character class`.

Comment: This works great thanks

Comment: I will post it as answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match `/foo/{{variable}}/images` where `{{variable}}` is a string having multiple characters from range `a-z` use following regex.

**Regex**: `/\/foo\/([a-z]+)\/images/`

**Explanation**: It matches multiple characters between `/foo/` and `/images`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW1aG8/3)**</kbd>